# How can I output a favicon <link> in the HTML head section using JSF 2.0?

Tags: jsf, resources, jsf-2, favicon

Using h:outputStylesheet I can embed CSS resources in the HTML head section, but how can I build a `<link>` for a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) image resource which renders HTML like in this example:

HTML output:

```
<head>
... 
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
...
</head>
```

The image resource is located in `<web>/resources/images`.

If I use direct HTML code in the JSF template like `href="/resources/images/favicon.png"` the resource is not found - navigating to /resources/images/favicon.png leads to the error

> /resources/images/favicon.png/index.jsf
>   not found

(I have set index.jsf as index page in web.xml which might explain this path)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your webapp is apparently running on a non-empty context path. The leading slash `/` brings you to the domain root. Use `#{request.contextPath}` to dynamically inline the context path.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/favicon.png" />
```

*(note that I fixed the `rel` as well to make it crossbrowser compatible)*

Answer (score 2):

The `href="/resources/images/favicon.png"` is actually looking in the root direcotry of your server http://localhost/resources/images/favicon.png and not inside your web application directory.

Your href location will need to include the web application directory `href="/webappname/resources/images/favicon.png"`  http://localhost/webappname/resources/images/favicon.png

---

If your .xhtml file is in the same directory as your resources folder then removing the forward slash at the being should work as well.
`href="resources/images/favicon.png"`

Comment: the web app name can be set at deployment time, using it in a hard coded resource could be dangerous. In my example, the app is deployed at the server root `http://localhost:8080/` directly

Comment: @BalusC I don't mean in resources folder like this /web/index.xhtml and /web/resources/